# how to add multiselect checkbox by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add multiselect checkbox by clicking on button.i am using bootstrap multiselect.If anything other than bootstrap multiselect is also ok.
functionalities are not working for mutiselct checkbox after clicking on button.

```js
$('#addSupplierbtn').click(function(){
   $('#webhost').html($('#multipleSupplier').html());
});
```

```html
<div id="multipleSupplier" >
  <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="checked[]" id="chked" class='multiselect' >
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: It works if you hold the CTRL key

Comment: @wateriswet yeah i know.what i am asking is i want another copy of multiple select in div id webhost without broking any functionality of multiselect checkbox

Answer (score 1):

```js
var counter = 0;


$('#addSupplierbtn').click(function(){
  
    var anotherselect = $('.multiselect:nth-child(1)').clone();
  anotherselect.attr('id', "multiselect"+counter)
   $('.multiselect').last().after(anotherselect);
  counter ++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multipleSupplier" >
  <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="checked[]" id="multiselect" class='multiselect' >
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
    <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
    <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
    <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
    <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
  </select>
</div>

<input type='button' id='addSupplierbtn' value='Another Select'>
```

Try this way..

Comment: thanks.it is working but when i tried to check options on second drop down it is also affecting first multiselet

Comment: @vijaikarthik i have added a `dynamic ID` you can just use a variable and increment the variable to determine which `ID` to use

Comment: checked. it  just gives clone of the another multiselect.as i said before when second drop down checkboxes is checked it is shown in first dropdown too.

Comment: because it is clone.if you want new select change the value of the variable `anotherselect` into a new select

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#addSupplierbtn').click(function(){
    $('#webhost').html($('#multipleSupplier').html());
});
```

```html
<div id="multipleSupplier" >
    <select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="checked[]" id="chked" class='multiselect' >
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="option6" selected="selected">Option 6</option>
        <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
        <option value="option8">Option 8</option>
        <option value="option9">Option 9</option>
        <option value="option0">Option 10</option>
    </select>
</div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Comment: i got another copy of div.but some functionalities are missing .

Comment: What did this code change from the code that the OP posted? It would be helpful if you could add an explanation about what you changed and why.